# Установка ubuntu/mint на виртуалку - Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, linux-mint

Есть виртуальная машина virtual box, на нее пробовал устанавливать различные версии mint и ubuntu. Все время пишет this kernel requires an x86-x64 kernel, but only detected an i686 cpu. unable to boot -please use a kernel appropriate for your cpu. Проц intel i5-3470. Где найти соответствующий образ или как побороть сию проблему? убунту брал отсюда http://ubuntu.ru/get mint -17.2-cinnamon-64bit

Comment: а базовая система 32битная или 64? Очень похоже, что 32битная.

Comment: в том то и дело, что стоит x64 сервис пак первый

Comment: залезть в биос и включить виртуализацию, тогда будет поддержка 64 разрядов

Comment: @maint: тут ваш комментарий оказался ответом. Не хотите ли опубликовать как ответ?

Answer (score 2):

Сработало решение из [комментария maint](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446230/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-ubuntu-mint-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-ubuntu-linux/454207?noredirect=1#comment472839_446230):

> залезть в биос и включить виртуализацию, тогда будет поддержка 64 разрядов

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Лучше проголосуйте за ответы, которые оказались полезными.

Comment: @Visman: кстати, тут полезным оказался комментарий )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, значит этот ответ нужно отметить как решение :P

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

VM_NAME="test-vm"

vboxmanage createvm --name "$VM_NAME" --ostype Ubuntu_64 --register

vboxmanage modifyvm "$VM_NAME" --memory 2048 --floppy disabled --audio none --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0 --vram 16 --accelerate3d off --boot1 net --acpi on --cableconnected1 on --usb off --vrde on --vrdeport 7766 --draganddrop bidirectional --clipboard bidirectional
```

С такими параметрами тоже не хочет?